# Ajax select list not working when IE is launch from WatiN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery, watin

This issue that I'm having is not even a synchronization issue, where I'm waiting for the Ajax request to complete.  I am having a problem where the ajax post doesn't even get triggered when IE is launched by WaitN.  Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form select").change(function () {
        $(this).parents().filter("form").trigger("submit");
    });

    $("form#theForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        hijack(this, UpdateList, "html");
    });

    function hijack(form, callback, format) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            dataType: format,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: callback
        });
    }

    function UpdateList(result) {
        $("#results").html(result);
    }
```

Here is the html:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerName", "ActionName", FormMethod.Post, new { id="theForm" })) { %>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
               &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                Fiscal Year & Period: <%= Html.DropDownList("period", Model.FiscalPeriodSelectList)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <% } %>

    <div id="results">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("Setup", Model.ViewModel); %>
    </div>
```

Absolutely nothing happens when a different value is selected in the selectList.  I've even left the browser open after test were done running so that I could manually change the select list.  Still -- nothing happens.  However, when I run the app though VS, the ajax post on the select list works perfectly.  Is there something that's I'm not configuring properly?

Edit:  It may be important to note that I am logging in using Basic Authentication, both when I run the mvc app manually and when NUnit is running it.  After further inspection, I realized that the everything but the AJAX call back is getting executed and when I capture the AJAX error in an "alert", I being shown "Unauthorized".  I am still unsure how I can fix my issue and why I'm getting Unauthorized when I run my WatiN tests from NUnit, but I'm not getting it when I use the mvc application manually.

Comment: Are you sure that your paths to JQuery and any other scripts work when you are not running under the http://localhost:port/ of the VS engine?  Meaning - is your test site in a sub directory or something that is causing your JS files to not load properly?

Comment: It seems like everything is fine with the directories for the script files.

Comment: well I meant your paths in your head tag more so than did your scripts deploy.  As a test, have an alert('hi'); statement in your $(document).ready(function ()) function.  Does it work?

Comment: It does, but it disappears on it's own after about 1 second.

Comment: actually when the page is first brought up by WatiN, the alert doesn't display.  If I keep the page up after the test is finished running (and fails), then manually go to the page, the alert displays, but it disappears on its own (which probably has something to do with WatiN launching the browser)

Comment: I just realized that the only thing that is not getting executed is the callback function.  Not sure why this is.

Comment: I dug further an realized that the Ajax request is returning "Unauthorized".  Still not sure why?

Comment: I am also having this same issue now. Any update on a potential fix?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that I usually have a javascript error on page when running tests in Watin. I was told that is because we are not waiting for the page to load the JS file.

Do you see a JS error in the Status bar of your Browser? If so, you may want to delay the interaction your are trying to perform with Browser. That way we allow the JS file to be loaded and hopefully your issue should be resolved. Let us know how it goes. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am not seeing a JS error in the Status Bar.  I am however using Basic Authentication for my tests, so I'm wondering if it has anything to do with that.  I mentioned before that if I capture the AJAX error, it is giving me "Unauthorized"